# How to find out which Windows Firewall rule Scope an Ip Address Exists In

Tags: windows-firewall

I wrote my own IPS/IDS. For each ip address it blocks, it puts it in a Windows firewall rule that references the country code. So, I have ~300k ip addresses across ~185 firewall rule scopes and ended up blocking one of Cloudflare's Ip addresses that I need to operate one of my sites correctly.

Obviously, my IDS needs more features so this type of thing won't happen... However, before I write another something to find the ip, I thought I'd post the question here...

Does anyone know how to find which firewall rule scope an ip address exists in? Either through the searching/filtering in the UI? Or maybe a powershell or other clever command?

Answer (score 0):

I created a little program to do it. This is the best I can do without killing too much time:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            string ip;
#if DEBUG
            args = new[] { "192.168.169.1" };
#endif


            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter an IP address.");
                Console.WriteLine("Usage:   FindIpInFWRule any IPv4 or IPv6 address.");
                Console.WriteLine("Example: FindIpInFWRule 127.0.0.1");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                ip = args[0];
            }
                var firewallPrefix = "_IDS_Blocklist_";
        
                INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
                var firewallRules = firewallPolicy.Rules.OfType<INetFwRule>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(firewallPrefix)).ToList();
        
                //Loop through the firewall rules
                foreach (var fwRule in firewallRules)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fwRule.Name);
                    var ipExists = fwRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(ip);
        
                    if (ipExists)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ip + " (contains) exists in " + fwRule.Name);
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                 }
      }
```

All my rules have a prefix that separates them from the numerous other rules. However, if you want to search all firewall rules, just remove the linq where clause like so:

```
var firewallRules = firewallPolicy.Rules.OfType<INetFwRule>().ToList();
```

Just throw this code in a Visual Studio console project (**add a COM reference to NetFwTypeLib**) and use it by going to a command console and typing the program name followed by the ip address as the first argument.

I would still love to know if there's a way to do this inherently if anyone knows.